# Predefined functions for Binary trees in Isabelle

Tags: binary-tree, isabelle

Are there any predefined functions for binary trees in Isabelle?
For example to move to the left side of a binary tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Isabelle2014, there is a small theory for binary trees in `~~/src/HOL/Library/Tree`. If this type fits your purpose, you can use it and the functions defined on it. For example, there are selector functions `left` and `right` that return the left and right subtree of a tree.

If you have to define your own datatype, you can use the selector syntax of `datatype_new` to define selectors as you see fit.